# React native: Component not defined? Can't import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Ok, very new to react native here and Im trying to very simply import another .js file and have that be run in the main `render()` func in index.ios.js

I have looked everywhere and tried both `import and require` to do this, however I am stuck with error:

[image: Component is not defined]

Here is what I have, the error is thrown at just the addition of the import line:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-native-material-design';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
//import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';

import TestClass from "./TestClass";
//var animation = require('./TestClass');

//BODY
export default class SkysReact extends Component {


  render() {
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
    <TestClass/>
    </View>);

    // return (<View style={styles.container}>
    // {this.test()}
    // </View>);
  }
  test() {
  console.log("Hello World")
}

animate()
{
  console.log("animate");
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#404040',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#333333'
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SkysReact', () => SkysReact);
```

And my other class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

export default class TestClass extends Component { // not defined error here

    render() {
      return (<View style={styles.container}>
      {this.test()}
      </View>);
    }
    test() {
    console.log("Hello World 2222")
  }
}
module.exports = TestClass;
```

How can I just display TestClass in my index.ios.js? What is wrong?

Comment: You don't need the module.exports at the bottom of your component. You are already using export default in the class name. Quick sidenote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah hah. I know exactly what it is. Compare the very top line of your TestClass file with mine below. You will see the difference. Fix this, and your done.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
export default class TestClass extends Component {

    render() {
      return (<View style={styles.container}>
      {this.test()}
      </View>);
    }
    test() {
    console.log("Hello World 2222")
  }
}
```

You were missing the, {Component} in your import statement. I also took our your module.exports statement, its unnecessary.

Comment: Typically, the errors they give you are pretty good. Component is not defined, because you forgot to include it as part of the import statement at the top of your TestClass file.

Comment: `component is not defined`  (lower case C means that you have `extends component` instead of `extends Component`

Comment: That could happen too. The main reason was he didn't utilize the es6 destructuring at the very top of his TestClass component like he did correctly in his other component. import React, { Component } from 'react' is required if you want to call just "extends Component". Otherwise you'd have to do "extends React.Component".

Answer (score -2):

`this.test()` is not a valid child of your `<View>` in `TestClass` because it is not a valid React Component, nor does it return one.

If you want to "test" that your `TestClass.render()` function is running, put the `console.log()` above your `return` statement, like this:

```
render() {
  this.test();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}></View>
  );
}
```

Of course, you won't actually *see* anything because `TestClass` doesn't have any children.

Comment: No, I just copy pasted whatever I had in index.ios.js because I knew that return worked. I want to display TestClass's render, which will have a view and other container elements in it

Comment: How can I display TestClass?

Comment: Btw, that is valid React that he is using. You can insert a method like that into your JSX body and it will console.log the statement.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Yeah I suppose you're right since `this.test()` will just return `undefined`.